# Cordova Integration with OS' share menu and etc

Tags: apache, cordova, mobile, multiplatform

Sorry if this looks like a lazy question or inappropriate to the website's quality standards , but I searched in many forums and the Cordova API and couldn't find an answer to that. This is a legitimate question.

I am studying the possibility to use Apache Cordova to implement a series of applications for mobile OSs. One of my requisites is that it is able to integrate with specific features of the OS (as obvious as it seems as this is the point of this framework).

To give a few examples of features I am talking about:

- Share menu on Android: If you take a picture and then click on the
  share menu, it will open a list with all the available apps that
  supports sharing (ie. Facebook, Viber, WhatApp, Gmail...) [this is the most important];
- Open file types: If you click on a PDF file in any file explorer in
  Android, the system will give you a list of apps installed which
  support reading this file type.
- Be an "Account" source.

I can only give examples for Android as it's the only platform I have enough knowledge to enumerate such features, but I am sure other platforms support features equivalent to those as well.

Are Cordova apps able to "register" themselves in the platform, to tell it that they are able to perform these features?